# How to put angular 2 swing cards in Ionic 2 grid?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have recently followed this tutorial here https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-tinder-cards/ on using the Angular 2 swing package from Kapil Sachdeva. I have been able to add multiple swing components but I am now trying to get them to align horizontally. I have tried using the ionic 2 grid but have been unable, as it completely breaks the component. Any insight into how I could achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```html
  <ion-col>
  <ion-row>
  <div swing-stack #myswing1 [stackConfig]="stackConfig1" (throwoutleft)="voteUp1($event)" (throwoutright)="voteUp1($event)" id="card-stack1"[style.zIndex]="-1000">
    <ion-card #mycards1 swing-card *ngFor="let c of cards1; trackBy:trackByCards1 let t=index;"[style.zIndex]="-1*t" [style.marginTop]="t === 0 ? '0px':'0px'"(tap)="openModal1(cards1)">
        
          <img *ngIf="c"[src]="c"id="image">
  
    </ion-card>
  </div>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
   <div swing-stack #myswing2 [stackConfig]="stackConfig2" (throwoutleft)="voteUp2()" (throwoutright)="voteUp2()" id="card-stack"[style.zIndex]="-1000">
    <ion-card #mycards2 swing-card *ngFor="let p of cards2; trackBy:trackByCards2; let i=index;"[style.zIndex]="-1*i" [style.marginTop]="i === 0 ? '0px':'0px'"(tap)="openModal2(cards2)">
          <img *ngIf="p"[src]="p"id="image">
    </ion-card>
  </div>
  </ion-row>
  </ion-col>
```

Comment: could you add the code that you have tried so far to align them horizontally?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @gerdi ! just added the html I've tried using the ionic grid system.

Comment: Hi Matthew Bowman, I already fixed an issue with swing card in ionic. please check in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560017/conflicting-components-in-ionic-4-ioncard-and-swingcardcomponent]