# Can I use the plugin 'angular2-swing' in a project IONIC 5?

Tags: ionic5

Can I use the plugin 'angular2-swing' in a project IONIC 5?

I'm trying, but is not working the swipe card.

What plugin or example you recommend me?

I tried this example [Conflicting components in Ionic 4: IonCard and SwingCardComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560017/conflicting-components-in-ionic-4-ioncard-and-swingcardcomponent/66980169#66980169)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does works.

Try adding

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"> ' OR '
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css">
```

in your index.html and add

```
<script>
    if (global === undefined) {
      var global = window;
    }
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script> ' OR '
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```